# Search bar + select tag rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a search bar + a dropdown list to search for restaurants or meals and be able to filter by category (French food, Indian, foot, etc.)

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag meals_path, method: 'get', id: 'products_search' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= select_tag :search_category, options_for_select(@categories, @categories[0]) %>
    <%= submit_tag "Rechercher", name: nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

meals_controller.rb

```
@meals_search = @meals.search(params[:search], params[:search_category])
```

model/meal.rb

```
def self.search(search, search_category)
  if search
    if search && search_category == "All"
    where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
    elsif search == "" && search_category != "All"
      where('category = ?',  "%#{search_category}%")
    else
      where('name LIKE ? AND category = ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search_category}%")
    end
  else
    all
  end
end
```

the search bar works perfectly but the category filter (search_category) does not. I actually get an empty list although you can only filter with category that has at least one restaurant or meal (so the list can't be empty).

Any idea ?

Comment: Can you try `where('category = ?',  search_category)`. Also, what data type is category?

Comment: Could you post your params on form submit?

Comment: haven't followed question but be aware of `==` has precedence over `&&`

Comment: @SRack the params are the right one: if you search "Burger" in the search bar the params[:search] will be a string "Burger"; if you select "Indian" for search_category, then the params[:search_category] will be a string "Indian". Just checked.

Comment: @marmeladze sure, but It shouldn't be a big deal, still both conditions must be true, right ? otherwise what do you recommend ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so, following @vishnuprakash 's suggestion, I used the ransack gem to solve my issue:

I added `gem 'ransack'` to my `Gemfile` and ran `bundle`.

Then I created this form in my index.html.erb:

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>

  <%= f.search_field :name_cont %>

  <%= f.select :category_eq, options_for_select(@categories), include_blank: true %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

and meals_controller.rb:

```
 @q = @meals.ransack(params[:q])
      @meals_search = @q.result(distinct: true)
```

I also got rid of the function previously created in model/meals.rb.

It now works perfectly ! Do not hesitate to have a look at [the ransack dock](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) if you have similar issue. You can also DM me, I'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

just use ransack, for advanced searching and sorting

Comment: I'm gonna have a look at it and give a feedback then.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
where('name LIKE ? AND category = ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search_category}%")
```

to

```
where('name LIKE ? AND category = ?', "%#{search}%", search_category)
```

and

```
where('category = ?',  "%#{search_category}%")
```

to

```
where('category = ?',  search_category)
```

The `%...%` syntax only works with `LIKE`, not with `=`.

Comment: Then maybe `where('name LIKE ? AND category LIKE ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search_category}%")`

Comment: It is still empty !